# How to customize front-end exp:email:contact_form error

Tags: email-contact-form

I would like to know how to customize the displayed screen when the user didn't insert all the required inputs in a exp:email:contact_form.

"The default screen could show the next message:

The following errors were encountered

Email Message is Required
Return to Previous Page"

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most system error messages may be edited by making changes to the language files.  To find the message/file that you need to change, you can use the translation utility.

- For EE2: CP->Tools->Utilities->Translation Utility
- For EE3: CP->Developer->Utilities->CP Translation

I believe that is the EE way of doing things.
However, I would highly recommend that you use jQuery and the [jQuery Validation library](https://jqueryvalidation.org) to handle your error messages inline or on the page instead of messing with EE's error pages.  The EE error pages, while simple to use, do not really allow for fine grain modification. To me, it is much more user friendly to check validation during form input or on form submission and present a customized message and error highlighting so that the user knows right away what needs to be fixed and they don't have to jump between form and error page and back to fix it.

Furthermore, once you have the validation library working, you can quickly set up any form on input you need and validate the input with whatever requirements you have.  Custom messages are easy to setup per form or per site.

Edit:  since you seem to be wanting to customize the design and layout of the error page, you can do so a couple of different ways.

1. Edit the message templates found in the design user message section. Be sure to include the message tags that are specified there.
2. Use a user management extension like Solspace User or other similar mod that allows you to setup your own custom templates for redirection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to mean how to apply a new template or style to the EE error pages.

Comment: I updated my answer to account for layout and design as well. It's not perfect, but I hope it will point you in the right direction.